# Data validation using ng-blur in angularjs

Tags: json, database, angularjs, web-services

I have  web page which contains text field and submit button ,when text entered in text box and click on submit button the text is saved in database by using web service. Now I need to display  error or alert when user enter the already saved text in text field by using another web service .

html page :

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="add()">
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>NameEnter:</label>
             <input class="inputclass" ng-model="name" ng-blur="" required>
             <button type="submit" class="buttonclass">INSERT</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

script file:

```
$scope.add= function(){
 $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: http://localhost:8080/admin/addb    //web service for saving the data in db
  data: {
  "bname": $scope.name
  },
  headers: { 
  'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
   },
 }).
 success(function (data) {
 $location.path('/viewb');              //after saving  data go to view page
 });
 };
```

web service to check whether the text is in database or not :

```
http://localhost:8080/domain/services/common/actionPart?BName=test
```

where `BName` is argument and test is the value of argument. If `test` is already in database then it gives following information

Response Body:
action  Exists

Response Code:
200

Now  how can i display the error if the text is already in database ,if text is not in database then it has to save in database by using ng-blur in AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In success function you can check

```
 if(data.responseBody === 'action Exists') {
     $scope.actionExist = true;
  }
```

and in your view you can have something like this

```
<div ng-show="actionExist" > Error its exist </div>
```

Comment: where can i include this code in http function ? i want using  ng-blur

Comment: ok, lets clarify what you question ? you want to know how to do request on blur ? and depend on that result show/dont-show the message ?

Comment: yes ,if http://localhost:8080/domain/services/common/actionPart?BName=test response is action Exists then display a error message and response is not action Exists save the text in the db by using http://localhost:8080/admin/addb web service

Comment: in success function you can check the respnoseBody and depend on that make another call for add $http.post('http://localhost:8080/admin/addb',{data}) or show your error message

Answer (score 0):

you could create another web service for example

```
localhost:8080/domain/services/common/exists
```

and query the database to check if you can find rows with that content

Comment: The web service creation is not my hand ,the db people already given the actionPart web service and their nature ,i need to find out that text box text is in db or not ,if it is in db then through error